# $M$ = $\{x \in E : \{T_n(x)\}$ is a Cauchy sequence$\}$. Show that $M$ is a closed set.

Tags: functional-analysis, linear-transformations

Let $E,F$ bereal or complex normed linear spaces. Let $T_n : E \to F$ be a sequence of continuous linear transformations such that $sup_n ||T_n|| < \infty$. Let $M$ = $\{x \in E : \{T_n(x)\}$ is a Cauchy sequence$\}$. Show that $M$ is a closed set.

My approach : First we take a sequence $\{x_n\}$ in $M$ which converges to some $x$ in $E$ then we need to show $x$ also belongs to $M$.

As $T_n$ is continuous for each $n$, we have $T_n(x_m) \to T_n(x)$ in $F$. So given $\epsilon > 0$, choose $N$ such that $||T_n(x) - T_n(x_m)|| < \epsilon/3$ for all $m \ge N$ and for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Now for $m > N$ we get, $||T_n(x) - T_m(x)|| \le ||T_n(x) - T_n(x_k)|| + ||T_n(x_k)-T_m(x_k)|| + ||T_m(x_k)-T_m(x)|| < \epsilon/3 + \epsilon/3 + \epsilon/3 = \epsilon$, since for the middle term $x_k \in M$, hence by Cauchy property.

I do not understand where $sup_n ||T_n|| < \infty$ is needed. Is it unnecessary? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In your proof $N$ depends on $n$ so the proof is not valid. Use the fact that $$\|T_nx-T_mx\|$$ $$ \leq \|T_n\| \|x-x_k\|+\|T_n(x_k)-T_m(x_k)\|+\|T_m\|\|x_k-x\|$$ $$ \leq 2M\|x_k-x\|+\|T_n(x_k)-T_m(x_k)\|$$
where $M=\sup_n \|T_n\|$, to get valid proof.

Comment: Oh, yes. Thank you for correcting me.